# Rails - on save - go back to previous page (or page where the user clicked 'edit')

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2

Bit stuck on this one as I have found a lot of information but none of it seems to work.

The user can edit a Client from one of two screens, the Clients index, or the home screen. I want the update to send them back to the screen they clicked the edit button on.

- First thing I found which sounded perfect was: `redirect_to :back`
- Second thing which seemed to be along the lines was: `request.referer` or `request.env['HTTP_REFERER']`

Both of these 'solutions' simply loaded the edit screen again and didn't send the user back to the index screen or the home screen.

Here is my update def:

```
def update
  @client = Client.find(params[:id])
  if @client.update_attributes(params[:client])
    redirect_to clients_path, notice: "#{@client.name} (#{@client.company}) was successfully updated."
  else
    render action: "edit"
  end
end
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got to this bottom of this.

`:back` and `request.referer` were working as expected - e.g. passing from edit form to the controller, the edit form of course *was* then the referrer. So, I needed to have a hidden field on the form that held the referring URL.

I added this to my form partial: `<%= hidden_field_tag :referrer, request.referer %>`

I used `hidden_field_tag` so I just had a variable called referrer, I didn't want it in any array being made by simple forms based off the model name etc

Then in the controller I added `redirect_to params[:referrer]` and **voila!**, everything works a treat.

I can now click the edit button I have on the homepage, and once saved, I get taken back to the homepage, or if I click edit button on the index page I get taken back there, simples!

NB - Minor concern of security. I might end up sending a variable in the hidden field tag and then interpret that variable inside the controller. e.g. referrer value 1 goes to homepage, value 2 goes to index. I assume that's more 'safe' as the two choices are paths I would set explicitly. I'll sort that later and update this if need be!